Equivalent of JsonConstructor for serialization?
ASP.NET provides a handy JsonConstructor annotation for deserializing a complex type from a string:
public record Point
{
    public int X { get; init; }
    public int Y { get; init; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Point(string point)
    {
        var m = Regex.Match(point, @"(\d+),(\d+)");
        X = int.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value);
        Y = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{X},{Y}";
    }
}

Now, Point will be deserialized as intended from strings like "7,2".
Is there a simple way to do the reverse, i.e. have Point serialize using the ToString() method?

That is not really the main purpose of JsonConstructor... The idiomatic way to do this is writing your own JsonConverter.

It can be done utilizing JsonConverter:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
public record Point {
    public int X, Y;
    public Point(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{X}, {Y}";
    public class PointJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Point> {
        public override Point Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
            using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
            var re = jsonDoc.RootElement;
            var p = re.GetString().Split(',');
            return new Point(Convert.ToInt32(p[0]), Convert.ToInt32(p[1]));
        }
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Point point, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
            writer.WriteStringValue($"{point.X},{point.Y}");
        }
    }
}

class PointConsumer {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Point.PointJsonConverter))]
    [JsonInclude]
    Point p;
    public PointConsumer Set(int x, int y) { p = new Point(x, y); return this; }
    public override string ToString() => p.ToString();
}

    internal class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        File.WriteAllText("point.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(new PointConsumer().Set(3, 4)));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PointConsumer>(File.ReadAllText("point.json")));
    }
}

-->

3, 4

point.json --> {"p":"3,4"}

PointJsonConverter defines Write and Read methods to process Point where it's directed by the JsonConverter attribute.
It's more or less the recommended way but the JsonConverter attribute should applied on every mention of Point.

It can be resolved in such way:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public record Point {
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int X { get; init; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Y { get; init; }
    public string Json => $"{X}, {Y}";
    public Point(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Point(string json) {
        var m = json.Split(',');
        X = int.Parse(m[0]);
        Y = int.Parse(m[1]);
    }
}

internal class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        File.WriteAllText("point.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Point(3, 4)));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Point>(File.ReadAllText("point.json")));
    }
}

-->

3, 4

point.json --> {"Json":"3, 4"}

The only property to write is Json which value can provide as necessary. The rest of properties should be ignored by the JSON serializer.
The Json constructor processes the Json parameter as necessary.
